# rails - what exactly does hidden_field and hidden_field_tag do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field

I read through the techy definition of `hidden_fields`, but am not sure what it really does.  My understanding is that it allows you to pass in an attribute for certain parameters.  For example, if you have a rich join model, you can use the `hidden_field` to assign the user_id to the join model attribute for user. Is that correct?

If so, would it be better to do it in the form or the controller?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both of those methods are helpers to create an HTML input tag of type "hidden", and yes, those are used to add parameters to a request (typically a form POST).  Really the parameter can be any piece of information you want to send along with a request.  Be careful, though, as hidden fields are easily tampered with.

Here's an example that will send a user id in a hidden field

```
# Form
<%= form_tag foo_path do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "user_id", @user.id %>
  ....
  <%= submit_tag "Click Me" %>
<% end %>

# Controller
def foo
  # params[:user_id] is set with the value from the hidden field
  # Do useful stuff with the POST data
end
```

While you can pass things such as user_id's like this, I find that the need for it is rare.  If a user_id is always required for a given situation you might consider using nested routes http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources.

Comment: Thanks @wizard of ogz.  I thought `hidden_field` would not be safe.  I am trying to save it via the controller in the `create` method, but am encountering trouble.  When you make associations via rich join models, are they supposed to update things like user_id automatically?  If so, I am obviously doing something wrong with my associations.  Thanks.  I also posted another question here: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740873/nested-attributes-not-saving-the-user-id-in-join-table) if you want to take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I think the problem is better explained in the other question, I'll post there

Answer (score 16):

It would generate a hidden type of input field...

`<input type="hidden" />`

This is a way to store information that you want submitted with the form without having to have a visible field.

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag):

`hidden_field_tag 'tags_list'` generates...
`<input id="tags_list" name="tags_list" type="hidden" />`

`hidden_field_tag` is meant to be used without a model whereas `hidden_field` is meant to be used in conjunction with a `form_for` call and a model.

`hidden_field(:signup, :pass_confirm)` generates...
`<input type="hidden" id="signup_pass_confirm" name="signup[pass_confirm]" value="#{@signup.pass_confirm}" />`