# nested attributes not saving the user_id in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-attributes

**Admin Main controller:**

```
def new
  @admin = Admin.new
  @invitation = @admin.invitations.build
  @admi.user_admin_relationships.build
end

def create
  params[:invitation][:sender_id] = current_user.id
  @admin = Admin.new(params[:admin])
  if @admin.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**Invitation Model**

```
belongs_to :admin
belongs_to :user
```

**Admin Model**

```
has_many :invitations
has_many :user_admin_relationships
has_many :users, :through => :user_admin_relationships

accepts_nested_attributes_for :invitations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_admin_relationships, :allow_destroy => true
```

**User Model**

```
has_many :invitations
has_many :user_admin_relationships
has_many :admins, :through => :user_admin_relationships
```

My forms are nested forms and it works fine saving the fields per the form and items such as `created_at` and `sent_at`.  **However, it does not save the `user_id` (user_admin join table) and `sender_id` (invitation table).**

I tried adding different permutations to the admin controller, but nothing is working.

**Things that does not work:**

```
params[:invitation][:sender_id] = current_user.id
```

This gives me I have a nil object when I didn't expect it error.

```
params[:invitation].merge!(:sender_id = current_user.id)
```

This give me a "wrong syntax error"

```
@admin.invitations.build(params[:invitation][:sender_id]) = current_user.id
```

This gives me unexpected "=" and "expecting keyword end" error

I have tried a bunch of other different permutations as well.  Is there something wrong with my associations?  How can I update the `sender_id` in the invitation table and the `user_id` in the rich join user_admin_relationship table?  I know I can do it via a `hidden_field`, but heard it's not safe so I don't want to do that.

Comment: Should the "user_id" come from the current user?

Comment: the `sender_id` should be `user_id`, which is the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
params[:invitation].merge!(:sender_id => current_user.id)
```

Notice the `=>`, whereas you just has `=`. However, in your `create` action, you are adding that to `params[:invitation]`, but then you aren't saving that anywhere, so it's just getting lost. You probably want to use:

```
params[:admin][:invitations_attributes][:sender_id]
```

Also, you are storing `sender_id` but you don't have anything to tell your User model to look for `sender_id` as the foreign key. By default it will look for `user_id`. You have to add this:

```
User: has_many :invitations, :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
```

and either:

```
Invitation: belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User" # recommended
# or 
Invitation: belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I knew I messed up with the associations a bit.  The sender_id is no longer null, but it's not taking the user_id number.  Instead it is autoincrementing the `sender_id` as well as the `invitation_id`. Using the `params[:invitation].merge!(:sender_id => current_user.id)` in my create method brought up the error "undefined method merge!"?