# How do I pass in a parameter to a hidden_field_tag in my form in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, simple-form

I'm trying to get a messaging feature working (using the [acts-as-messageable](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable) gem) and I want a user to send a message without having to enter a ':to' field.

In my /users/show.html.erb I have:

```
<%= link_to 'Send a message', new_message_path %>
```

And in my /messages/new.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, :url => messages_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id %> 
   <%= f.input :body %>
   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

And my messages controller:

```
def new
  @message = ActsAsMessageAble::Message.new
 end

 def create
   @to = User.find(params[:user_id])
   current_user.send_message(@to, params[:body])
 end
```

At the moment when I submit the form, Rails obviously can't find a user with id= *nothing* since there is no param[:user_id] present.

I can't figure out how to pass the param into that hidden_field_tag in the form?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I wanted to do was visit a users profile, click send message, and be able to write the the message and let it send automatically to the user without explicitly stipulating a :to field.

The problem was that :user_id in `<%= hidden_tag_field :user_id %>` wasn't being set. In other words, I couldn't get :user_id from the params while in that form.

Some of the solutions we tried were to include the params in the link_to but that didn't sit well with the form which saw the object as nil.

What I ended up doing was creating a nested resource like so:

```
resources :users do
   resources :messages do
   end
 end
```

And this ultimately gave me the url: users/:id/messages/new (`new_user_message_path`)

My controller ended up looking like this:

```
def new
   @message = ActsAsMessageable::Message.new
   @user = params[:user_id]
 end

 def create
   @to = User.find params[:id]
   if current_user.send_message(@to, params[:acts_as_messageable_message][:body]
     flash[:notice] = "Success"
   else 
     flash[:error] = "Fail"
   end
 end
```

In the form I was able to leave `<%= hidden_tag_field :user_id %>` as is.

But basically that solved the problem of finding the user (whose profile I was visiting) and setting the @to in my create action.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my iPhone so sorry for the brief reply, you just need to pass in the user id into the hidden field, you can find the syntax in the answer here:

[rails - what exactly does hidden_field and hidden_field_tag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733085/rails-what-exactly-does-hidden-field-and-hidden-field-tag-do)

Edit: just noticed - this
   <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id %>

Should be this:
   <%= f.hidden_field_tag :user_id %>

Try passing the params into the create method like this:

User.find(params[:message][:user_id])

Comment: Thanks I saw that question, but I tried adding: `<%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>` and I keep getting the error "Called id for nil... if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id.

Comment: Can you try :value => @user.id

Comment: Tried that and still the same error message. I checked the logs and there is no param[:id] being sent when the form is being submitted.

Comment: put f. In front of it like the others.

Comment: Oops. That still didn't work though. Since it's a form_for `@messages`, could `@user` be nil because I'm not passing it into the block? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Make it a visible text field and make sure the value is displaying. Can you paste the post log?

Comment: Try this on the create for the params :  User.find(params[:message][:user_id])

Comment: Sorry that didn't fix it. I think going back to the main issue, the problem is that I'm trying to send a message without having an input for the :to field. The idea is that when you view a users profile and click 'Send Message' it passes the id of that user so I can use it to identify who the recipient will be. I'm not sure editing the `create` action will fix that - my thinking is the params[:id] of the user should be passed to the view users/new.html.erb and then onto the `create` action, but I don't know how and not sure if that's even the right way.

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood. In the link to do this: <%= link_to 'Send a message', new_message_path (:user_id => @user.id)%> then in your form <%= f.hidden_field_tag :user_id, :value => params[:user_id] %>

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I figured it out. I tried passing the params in the link_to but that didn't work. I ended up creating a nested resource which gave me the id of the profile I was viewing, which I could then use to identify the @to in my `create` action. I wrote an answer to submit here but there's an 8hr buffer for noobs submitting answers to their own questions on StackOverflow :s Thanks for all your help though.

Comment: That's great! But if the user is logged in you should always be able to grab the id for a hidden field, not sure why it didn't work for you.