# undefined method `hidden_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x5c03e80>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to pass an array to my ruby controller through a `hidden_field_tag`, with a form but I am getting the error:

```
NoMethodError in Events#new
undefined method `hidden_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x5c03e80>
```

which is highlighting the line:

```
<%= f.hidden_field_tag 'id_array[]', [], id: 'extra_ids'  %>
```

What is the problem here? How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try this `<%= f.hidden_field ... %>` without the "tag" word at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `f.`, you don't need it for `hidden_field_tag`.

UPDATE

> hidden_field_tag is meant to be used without a model whereas
>   hidden_field is meant to be used in conjunction with a form_for call
>   and a model.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7733610/338536

Comment: yep! that was it thank you! I will accept your answer when I'm allowed

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using model's form helper?

If so, it should be

`<%= f.hidden_field 'id_array[]', [], id: 'extra_ids'  %>`