# Passing an argument on request.referrer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I'm building a site where a link to fill a new form can be clicked from an `Event show page`

```
<%= link_to 'Be a Contestant', new_form_path(:event_id => @event.id)%>
```

This  creates a link like

```
http://localhost:3000/forms/new?event_id=2
```

Now if the form is filled with an error, when submitted, it returns an error

```
Couldn't find Event with 'id'=""
```

So I decided to use the `request.referrer` to redirect back to the previous page but it doesn't list the errors as  use this method

```
def create
  @form = Form.new(form_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @form.save
      format.html { redirect_to @form, notice: 'Form was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @form }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to request.referrer }
      format.json { render json: @form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I also tried this but to no avail.

```
def create
  @form = Form.new(form_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @form.save
      format.html { redirect_to @form, notice: 'Form was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @form }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to new_form_path(:event_id => request.referrer.params[:event_id]) }
      format.json { render json: @form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably really need to do is to add a hidden field `event_id` to the form because I'm betting that `event_id` doesn't get propagated from the `#new` to the `#create` action.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733085/rails-what-exactly-does-hidden-field-and-hidden-field-tag-do) for more information on `hidden_field_tag`

Answer (score 0):

You usually just render the `edit` view when there was an error in `create`:

```
def create
  @form = Form.new(form_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @form.save
      format.html { redirect_to @form, notice: 'Form was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @form }
    else
      format.html { render :edit, alert: 'Error creating ...' }
      format.json { render json: @form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```